Google Sheets: How to have multiple cells reference/update the same dynamic drop down list?
I have just started (ie, less than a month ago) trying to dive into using google sheets properly. I am currently trying to create a self updating and detailed gaming sheet for Pathfinder 2e Kingmaker. Admittedly less professional than much I see on this site, but I have learned a lot here and am hopeful.
Current Issue:
I am attempting to have multiple, non connected cells reference the same data set for a two tier dynamic drop down list. There are a number of actions that can be taken each turn in various ways, and each action has different skills tied to it.
I need a way to have a character be able to select an action, auto populate the list of skills in a second cell, then select a cell from that. That cell will then be referenced elsewhere.
I have looked into both lookup and indirect, but I haven't found a way to actually get the data where I need it.
With lookup, I am able to reference the cells and populate an area for the drop down, but I would need to build a separate version of the table for each instance of the drop down, which would be a huge amount of space.
This is the base I was using: =TOROW(XLOOKUP(B9,$C$9:$Z$9,C10:$Z25,),1)
However, in this case, B9 is not the desired final location. This specific drop down would be needed upwards of 25 times per turn, and I was hoping to have each cell change B9 for what they need (off of the most recent change request to it) and then take from the drop down so another cell could use it.
I also looked into =indirect(B9) and a number of labeled zones, which populates fine, but most of the actions have spaces in their names, like Pledge of Fealty or Establish Trade Agreement, which don't play nice with Named Ranges.
Example Attempt: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1gDMy5I176Wxq2f0e8TbTO9bF8HLLIryPONd-lExTgDE/edit?usp=sharing
I am fairly certain that the answer to this is either something simple I missed, or some sort of script, which I'll probably have to look into learning for another part of the sheet.
Any advice would be appreciated.
Solution:
My solution was to write a script for it. The script I used is added below, in a shortened form:
function RegionActionCheck(e) {
  var KingdomSheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById("ID");
  var SheetsKingdomTurn = KingdomSheet.getSheetByName("Kingdom Turn Template");
  // Region Actions selection
var RegionActions = [
    SheetsKingdomTurn.getRange("V47"),
...
];
// Skill dropdown location based on Action chosen
  var RegionSkillChoices = [
    SheetsKingdomTurn.getRange("W47"),
...
  ];
  // Check if Region Action is chosen in edited cell
  for (var i = 0; i < RegionActions.length; i++) {
    if (e.range.getA1Notation() === RegionActions[i].getA1Notation()) {
      var selectedAction = RegionActions[i].getValue();
      var Skills = getSkillsForRegionAction(selectedAction);
      // Clear existing validations and set new one
      RegionSkillChoices[i].clearDataValidations();
      if (Skills.length > 0) {
        var rule = SpreadsheetApp.newDataValidation().requireValueInList(Skills).setAllowInvalid(false).build();
        RegionSkillChoices[i].setDataValidation(rule);
      }
      break; // Exit the loop
    }
  }
}

// Leadership Actions as tied to Skills
function getSkillsForRegionAction(action) {
  switch (action) {
    case "Claim Hex":
      return ["Exploration", "Intrigue", "Magic", "Wilderness"];
...
    default:
      return []; // Return an empty array if no match
  }
}


Hi! Welcome to Stackoverflow. Provide a Minimal Reproducible Example: create a dummy sheet highlighting your data, show the expected results, and include a manually entered expected result. This will give the community a clearer understanding of your problem and what you’re aiming to achieve.
